# Тернарный оператор в цикле for

Tags: c, циклы, тернарный-оператор

```
int main(void) {

  int N = -3, M = 4;

  for (N > 0 ? N : 1;N <= M; printf("%d ", N++)){
  }

  return 0;
  }
```

На выводе кода выше имеем:

```
-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4
```

А не:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Почему? Ведь N должно присваиваться значение 1, исходя из условия и выражения тернарного оператора.
При создании дополнительной переменной всё работает так, как я ожидаю:

```
for ( int K = N > 0 ? K : 1 ; K <= M; printf("%d ", K++))
```

Что я упускаю?

Comment: Совет: не стоит писать подобные циклы, т.к. они ухудшают читаемость кода

Comment: `for (; K <= M; K++){
   if (K>0){
    printf("%d ", K);
 }
}`

Comment: Лучше что-то вроде такого?
Тут подразумевается, что K и M инициализированы ранее.

Comment: Да, но не одной строкой

Comment: "Ведь N должно присваиваться значение 1". Но у вас в коде нет никакого присваивания значения N...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Упускаете присвоить значение переменной `N`:

```
for (N = N > 0 ? N : 1; N <= M; printf("%d ", N++));
```

Код

```
N > 0 ? N : 1
```

*возвращает* значение, но вы им не пользуетесь...

Answer (score 2):

Можно и без тренарного оператора:

```
for (N = (abs(N-1)+N+1)/2;N <= M; printf("%d ", N++)){
}
```